How to use the ActiveX in Python
I have an ActiveX control from the vendor, with the filename "xxx.dll". I have a sample program from the vendor written in C#, and in Visual Studio, the property of that dll file shows the file type is ActiveX and the Identity of a long string {xxx}.
I'm trying to automate the use of that ActiveX file with Python 3.10. And found the link about how to create a python wrapper for it with Python2.7. However, I couldn't even find the makepy mentioned in that link. How could I use the ActiveX with Python 3.10? Thanks!
